# Fiz um carousel de varias imagens uma ao lado da outra que não fica responsivo em telas menores

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Então eu estava montando um projeto em que fiz um carousel com marcas de veículos em que uso 4 imagens em cada slide, que em tela de computadores fica certo mas quando se entra pelo celular para visualizar o site as imagens ficam uma embaixo da outra, segue o código abaixo lembrando que sou novo na área então qualquer erro podem dizer a vontade.

```
         <section class="marcas fundo_branco">
          <div class="container">
            <h2 class="tit"><strong>Principais Marcas Atendidas</strong></h2>
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div  class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/ford.png" height="200px" !important alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/cat.jpg" height="200px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/deere.jpg" height="200px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/iveco.jpg" height="200px">
                        </div>
                      </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/man.png" height="200px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/mercedez.png" height="200px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/new-holland.png" height="200px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <img src="imagens/imagens_marcas/scania.jpg" height="200px">
                        </div>
                      </div>  
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>         
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe com o "col-lg-3" o "col-xs-X".
Ex.:

```
       class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3"
```

Também verifique se está adicionando a meta tag no header:

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```